# Vectors-Scalar Triple product

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that

$$(a \times b) \times (c \times d)= [a,b,d]c - [a,b,c]d.$$

I understand $[a,b,d] = a \cdot (b \times d)$ and $[a,b,c] = a \cdot (b \times c)$ but not really sure where else to go with this.

Comment: [Can you use $a\times(b\times c)=(a\cdot c)b-(a\cdot b)c$?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product)

Comment: YES! Thank you that works.

Answer (score 2):

As Rahul mentioned: $$n \times (m \times o) = (n \cdot o)m - (n \cdot m)o$$

Then it follows: $$(a \times b) \times (c \times d) = (a \times b \cdot d)c -(a \times b \cdot c)d$$ Using the expressions you mentioned above this can be further simplified to:$$[a,b,d]c - [a,b,c]d$$